# Excel - lookup array based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have workbook, containing 4 major worksheets named as

1. BNF WEEK
2. BNF NEXT WEEK
3. BNF MONTH
4. MAIN

Now I am working in sheet named as MAIN and I want formula where, if cell R6 = 1 than fetch data from 1st sheet i.e. BNF WEEK if R6 = 2 than fetch data from 2nd sheet i.e. BNF NEXT WEEK, and so on

Currently using below formula

```
=INDEX('BNF WEEK'!$E$2:$E$500,MATCH($J10+L$5&L$7,'BNF WEEK'!$XER$2:$XER$543,0))*-L$6
```

Comment: Try `SWITCH`. e.g., `=SWITCH(R6,1,"BNF WEEK", 2, "BNF NEXT WEEK")`

Comment: Switch function not working in my excel 2016 version

Comment: Then use CHOOSE instead. `=CHOOSE(R6, "BNF WEEK", "BNF NEXT WEEK")`

Answer (score 0):

> =INDEX(CHOOSE(R6,'BNF WEEK'!$E$2:$E$500,'BNF NEXT WEEK'!$E$2:$E$500,'BNF MONTH'!$E$2:$E$500,Main!$E$2:$E$500),MATCH($J10+L$5&L$7,CHOOSE(R6,'BNF WEEK'!$XER$2:$XER$543,'BNF NXT WEEK'!$XER$2:$XER$543,'BNF MONTH'!$XER$2:$XER$543,Main!$XER$2:$XER$543),0))*-L$6